# Ambient Occlusion Error In Knitted Hair System

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I'm modeling my son's first plush and I followed [this series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XEJtdysJjc) to do so. I've even asked Bradley on his discord about this and he didn't know a fix for it.

I'm including the blend file below for reference to my nodes setup as it uses Bradley's custom nodes so it wouldn't make much sense even if I could get a good screenshot of the full nodes, which I can't on my 1080p display.

So, the way the knitting works is it uses a single knitting curve object, called the Knitting Unit, and a Geo Node setup drives the distribution across an object in a hair system. The Geo Nodes use a UV Map to distribute a texture on each individual knitting unit so that they are one color per knit, as it should be. It appeared in order to add some extra detail and the Ambient Occlusion that I'd have to use *Object Coordinates*, but there's something strange going on with the AO. It's creating an unnatural darkness in parts of my knitting objects and I've tried cleaning up the reference meshes for them, because there were faces cutting through other faces. But that didn't fix it, and playing with the node settings and such didn't help either.

[image: Photo of error in question]

I'm trying to go for as close to photo-realistic as I can get, and to have AO is a must for that. So I'm hoping there's a solution here and it isn't just an unsolvable bug.

Thank you all again for your continued support.

#### Blend file

[Link to my blend file](https://filebin.net/z2chb7czi6efku1y/HobbesPlushVer2.blend)

Comment: I'm no expert on geonodes or texture nodes, however that tutorial is using Blender 3.0. Be aware that some of the geonodes have changed between Blender version 3.0 and 4.0 (which is what you seem to be using) and for the shading the Principled BSDF node has changed too so it's possible that some of the changes are affecting the results you're seeing. I'll leave others here with more experience to comment further.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, that is an older version, but the full series extends into later versions. What I lifted from that particular video is how to make the Knitting Unit, but I followed a later video for the rest of my setup, and Bradley helped me work out most of the problems I ran into.

Comment: I don't know the tutorial, but looking at it quickly, it's using GN, and there are no GN in your file.  I can say, your material doesn't make sense, because it's using something as a normal, that is not a normal, and this is causing your black spots: basically, the normal input you're sending to your AO doesn't make any sense.  If somebody told you to do that, for the mesh you're showing in the file, they're wrong.

Comment: @Nathan Oh, so do you mean I don't want anything plugged into my AO Node's Normal? I made that call myself, it wasn't in the tutorial. The AO doesn't seem to be doing anything without the coordinates plugged into it, though? I'm not sure how to fix the GN not being in the blend. I see that my GN objects are hidden in viewport in my file, if you look in the Knit Objects folder, they're in there, if you didn't look there already.

Comment: There's probably a problem with versioning.  Your objects in Knit aren't outputting anything in 4.0.2.  Your ambient occlusion isn't doing anything (on my computer) because your object isn't being occluded by anything.  Giving it a nonsense normal makes it do something, but what it does is nonsense.

Comment: @Nathan Oh okay, really all I wanted was for it to self-occlude the knitting curves on the object. I guess I can't get help with that if the GN systems aren't packed into the blend file, though. I'm using 4.0.2 as well.

Comment: There are GN objects in there, but they're not outputting any geometry.  Your GN node groups appear to not be packed into the file, but linked from some other source that's not included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152131/discussion-between-cullen-tapprich-and-nathan).